# Call API using powershell see curl example

Tags: powershell, api

I have a curl script to call an API but would like to use Ps to call it in the form of a loop 100 times and store the output response code i.e 200 etc.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://my-api-url/224/employee' \
 --header 'URN-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
 --header 'URN: 224'
```

I tried to run this on PS using the code below.

```
 $urn = 224
 #$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 $url = "https://my-api-url/$urn/employee"
 $headers = @{
     'urn' = '224'
     'urn-token' = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 }
 Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url -Headers $headers
```

I get a 400 error bad request.

I can get the token using an external authentication mechanism, so that doesn't need to be taken care of in the code.

Comment: Use a HTTPS debugging proxy, such as Fiddler, to see the raw requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used nc -l 8000 (netcat) in osx on my computer as a test web server, and they looked the same, unless case matters.  I used http so I could see the text.  The first one is curl and the second one is powershell.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/index.html' --header 'URN-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'URN: 224'


$url = 'http://localhost:8000/index.html'              
$headers = @{
     'urn' = '224'
     'urn-token' = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 }
Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url -Headers $headers
```

```
nc -l 8000

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */*
URN-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
URN: 224


nc -l 8000

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
urn: 224
urn-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Darwin 19.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64; en-US) PowerShell/7.0.0
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I try with curl again, as i am using windows. I got a specific error message below.

curl: (1) protocol "'http not supported or disabled in libcurl

I then removed the single quotes and used double quotes, then I get the error {"statuscode": 404, "message": "Resource not found"}

Answer (score 0):

'curl', when using Windows PowerShell is an alias for Invoke-WebRequst and that real curl.

```
Get-Alias -Name curl | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest    
#>

Get-Alias -Definition Invoke-WebRequest | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                      Version Source
----------- ----                      ------- ------
Alias       curl -> Invoke-WebRequest               
Alias       iwr -> Invoke-WebRequest                
Alias       wget -> Invoke-WebRequest 
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Examples
# Results
<#
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.bing.com?q=how+many+feet+in+a+mile
$R.AllElements | where {$_.innerhtml -like "*=*"} | Sort { $_.InnerHtml.Length } | Select InnerText -First 5
the shortest HTML value often helps you find the most specific element that matches that text.
$R=Invoke-WebRequest http://www.facebook.com/login.php -SessionVariable fb
$FB
$Form = $R.Forms[0]
$Form | Format-List
$Form.fields
$Form.Fields["email"]="User01@Fabrikam.com"
$R=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://www.facebook.com" + $Form.Action) -WebSession $FB -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields
# Sends a sign-in request by running the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. The command specifies a value of "fb" for the SessionVariable parameter, and saves 
$R.StatusDescription
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973757(v=vs.85).aspx").Links.Href
#>
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Online
```

To use real curl in PowerShell, because of Command precedence ...

> [about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7)

... you have to use curl.exe and or the full UNC to curl.exe.

> If you do not specify a path, PowerShell uses the following precedence
> order  when it runs commands for all items loaded in the current
> session:
>
> 1 - Alias
>
> 2 - Function
>
> 3 - Cmdlet
>
> 4 - External executable files
>
> (programs and non-PowerShell scripts)

FYI...
Also due to industry at-large change for SSL sites, this must be in your code:

```
# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```